# Why am I getting an undeclared error for a function argument? (C)

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, arguments, undeclared-identifier

So I found this library called libsha1, and I wrote a simple program to test it.
When I go to compile it with `gcc -lsha1 -o sha1sum sha1sum.c`, however, it gives me the following error:

```
sha1sum.c: In function 'main':
sha1sum.c:30: error: 'byte' undeclared (first use in this function)
sha1sum.c:30: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
sha1sum.c:30: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

What am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libsha1.h>

void printByte(unsigned char);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        unsigned char hash[20];
        int i;

        #ifndef LIBSHA1_NO_CTX
                sha1_ctx ctx;
        #endif

        if (argc != 2)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }

        #ifdef LIBSHA1_NO_CTX
                sha1(hash, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        #else
                sha1_begin(&ctx);
                sha1_hash(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]), &ctx);
                sha1_end(hash, &ctx);
        #endif

        for (i=0; i<5; i++) printByte(byte); printf("\n");

        return 0;
}

void printByte(unsigned char byte)
{
        const char *digits = "0123456789abcdef";
        printf("%c%c", digits[byte / 16], digits[byte % 16]);
}
```

Comment: Post the source code as part of the post instead of posting a link. And the answer to your question is very much present in the second line of the error shown by the compiler, which also indicates which file and the line contains the error.

Comment: I pasted the code into the question, makes it feel less overly localized in my opinion.

Comment: @unwind: Cool, thank you. I wasn't aware you could edit other people's questions. (unless you're a moderator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined the variable called `byte` on line 30. Perhaps you meant to use the loop variable `i`?

Comment: Oh. \*facepalm\*
I was looking at line 38. Thank you. (In case you're wondering, I wanted to use `hash[i]`, not just `i`.)
I also noticed another issue with my code; I forgot to change the number of loop iterations.